# Segue from SKScene to UIViewController doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, skview

The structure of my storyboard:

1.Screen1 (UIViewController)

2.GameScreen (SKScene)

3.Screen3 (UIViewController)

I'm passing UIViewController self object from Screen1

```
//Screen1 class

@IBAction func onStartButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    Values.viewController = self
}
```

to GameScreen, when making a segue:

```
//GameScreen class 

struct Values {
   static var viewController: UIViewController!
}

class GameScreen: SKScene {...}
```

My task is to make a segue from GameScreen to Screen3 using object of Screen1, which has been passed from previous step:

```
Values.viewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toScoreSegue1", sender:  self)
```

Everything should work fine, since I dragged a segue from Screen1 to Screen3, gave it identifier "toScoreSegue1" and calling it using Screen1 object. However, nothing happens.

There is no error etc.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a problem!

By mistake, I called performSegue on wrong ViewController.

I had to call segue on ViewController that initialized SKScene view:

1.Screen1 (UIViewController)

2.GameScreen (SKScene) - has its own ViewController, which should be used instead of Screen1!

3.Screen3 (UIViewController)

I really hope somebody with same problem may find it helpful.